# PHP strpos() as a way to implement an swear word filter

Tags: php, strings, array

I wrote a short function that should check if user input does contain any bad words that I predefined inside `$bad_words` array. I don't even care to replace them - I just want to ban if there are any. The code seems to work as it should - in the example below will detect the quoted string `badword` and the function does return `true`.

My question: Is this a good way to use `foreach` and `strpos()`? Perhaps there is better way to check if `$input` contains one of the `$bad_words` array elements? Or is it just fine as I wrote it?

```
function checkswearing($input)
{
    $input = preg_replace('/[^0-9^A-Z^a-z^-^ ]/', '', $input);//clean, temporary $input that just contains pure text and numbers
    
    $bad_words = array('badword', 'reallybadword', 'some other bad words');//bad words array
    
    foreach($bad_words as $bad_word)
    {//so here I'm using a foreach loop with strpos() to check if $input contains one of the bad words or not
        if (strpos($input, $bad_word) !== false)
            return true;//if there is one - no reason to check further bad words
    }
    return false;//$input is clean!
}

$input = 'some input text, might contain a "badword" and I\'d like to check if it does or not';

if (checkswearing($input))
    echo 'Oh dear, my ears!';
else
{
    echo 'You are so polite, so let\'s proceed with the rest of the code!';
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most glaringly, `[^0-9^A-Z^a-z^-^ ]` reveals a lack of regex understanding. Your negated character class pattern breaks down as:

```
[^      #match any character not listed...
  0-9   #digits
  ^     #a caret symbol 
  A-Z   #uppercase letters
  ^     #a caret symbol
  a-z   #lowercase letters
  ^-^   #all characters found in the ascii table between ^ and ^
        #a literal space character
]
```

Read the pattern breakdown for yourself at regex101.com.
It could be condensed to `/[^\da-z-]+/i`

Next, it makes no sense to include any spaces in your blacklisted words if you are going to purge spaces from the user's input.

As KIKO mentioned, string case-insensitivity is imperative.

The honest truth is that finding bad words is a neverending rabbithole.  Every algorithm that you can think of will have holes in it.  If the algorithm doesn't have holes in it, it is then void of any real flexibility and will be too restrictive and unenjoyable for users.

People will add *n* number of hyphens between letters to circumvent your check.

This is fine as an academic/learning exercise, but ultimately you cannot win.

If your php version allows it, have a look at `str_contains()`.

Your early return in the loop is best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Two things I have noticed:

1. You remove all non-alpha-numeric characters, apart from the dash and space characters. I don't see what this adds to your filter? Clearly all the other characters are never part of your swear words, so why bother to remove them? It could, in theory, have unpredictable consequences, because formerly separated characters might form new words. Instead of removing you could replace the characters with a space, but my suggestion is to just don't do this step at all.
2. [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is case sensitive, that would mean your function won't find *"BadWord"* or *"BADWORD"* unless you add all these variants to your array. Better use [stripos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) which is case-insensitive.

Comment: In this way I'm creating a "clean" version of input that prevents user from cheating system by trying to type `BadWorD`, or `bad_wo.rd`. In fact I'm considering to add there `strtolower()` to cover Your point 2, but `stripos()` is a good solution as well.